# Run AIR Debug Launcher (ADL) without a GUI for continuous build

Tags: apache-flex, unit-testing, adobe, air, flexunit

Is it possible to run the ADL without a GUI so that I can run FlexUnit tests during a nightly build? Right now, when I execute our test runner on our server (Ubuntu 9.04) it fails with the output: "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:".

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

We use hudson with xvnc plugin and vncserver installed on the server.

Some instructions to follow can be found at:- http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Continuous_Integration_Support

A more specific example is at :- http://www.brianlegros.com/blog/2009/12/20/using-xvnc-to-create-headless-ci-builds-for-flex-and-air-applications/

Hope you come right. It's a bit of a pain to get working.

Comment: Hi Decado, I have marked your question as correct...but...I am indeed finding it a pain to get working. The problem I am having is the build just hangs after the output: ""LocalConnectionCoverageAgent.sendMaps: Nothing to send". I have read that I need to run the app as local trusted and then it should work but I have no idea how to do that (or it is even the right thing to do). Do you have any advice? Thanks again!

Comment: Will look into a bit further this afternoon, but perhaps set compile option use-network=false.